# Windows forms - overwritten visual contents of the window

Tags: c#, winforms

When I move another window over my application's window, sometimes the visual contents of my window gets overwritten with the contents of the other window.

How to avoid this?

Would WinAPI or unmanaged code help?

Answer (score 2):

This is likely happening because your app is single threaded and you are doing some time consuming CPU intensive or IO operation.

Recommended route would be to move the processing to another thread
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms951089

Although a quick and dirty could be to 'yield' intermittently using Application.DoEvents()